# Missing ghc-mod packages in stack project

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghc-mod, ghc-pkg

I recently broke something in my setup (probably stack upgrade) and found I cannot get it working again:

```
ghc-mod: <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id http-types-0.8.6-6a9e3ae2218aaee5f093c4f68fa256c5

$ stack list-dependencies | grep http
http-types 0.8.6
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.4.0 of the Cabal library
$ cabal info http-types | grep installed
    Versions installed: 0.8.6
```

I'm using recent `stack-support` branch. Why do I have this hash difference?

```
$ ghc-pkg dump | grep http-types
name: http-types
id: http-types-0.8.6-6f392f2a441fe60aa14d377f6850166a
```

Comment: Are you using a resolver that uses a different version of GHC than the one used for compiling ghc-mod? I've opened a bug report ([click](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues/605)) about the same message earlier today and the ghc-mod developers replied that ghc-mod should be recompiled against the same GHC version used by stack.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but I was just fighting this issue and I was able to solve it by removing the `dist/` directory in my project.

Comment: there is a pull request to at least WARN you when ghc-mod decides to drop stack support... https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/pull/671